# Jquery UI autocomplete accent map not working with slavic characters

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui

I made mysql database. I stored values in it. They are all utf8_unicode_ci.

I made jquery-ui autocomplete field that reads value from db.

```
$(function() {
var names = <?php echo json_encode($rows); ?>;

var accentMap = {
  "š": "s",
  "đ": "d",
  "č": "c",
  "ć": "c",
  "ž": "z",
  "Š": "S",
  "Đ": "D",
  "Č": "C",
  "Ć": "C",
  "Ž": "Z"
};
var normalize = function( term ) {
  var ret = "";
  for ( var i = 0; i < term.length; i++ ) {
    ret += accentMap[ term.charAt(i) ] || term.charAt(i);
  }
  return ret;
};

$( "#field1" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
    response( $.grep( names, function( value ) {
      value = value.label || value.value || value;
      return matcher.test( value ) || matcher.test( normalize( value ) );
    }) );
  }
});
});
```

When I insert value with some of characters from accent map my autocomplete stops working. When I remove value with special character everything works fine.
I got error in console on line where my var names are - Unexpected token. If I remove value with special character error is no longer there.

Someone had this problem?

EDIT:

my var_dump for $rows shows this:

```
 array (size=8)
 0 => string 'Split' (length=5)
 1 => string 'Hajduk' (length=6)
 2 => string 'Monkey' (length=6)
 3 => string 'First' (length=5)
 4 => string 'Zagreb' (length=6)
 5 => string 'Table' (length=5)
 6 => string 'Computer' (length=8)
 7 => string '�ibenik' (length=7)
```

and if I echo $rows i get this:

```
Array
```

If I remove row 7 everything works good.

Here is my php:

```
    global $rows;
    require_once ('database_connect.php');
    $query = 'SELECT words FROM tbl';
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    $rows = array();
    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $rows[] = $r['words'];
    }
```

And just to mention. In my database all characters are shown correct.

Comment: An `Unexpected token` seems to indicate that your php isn't working properly -- this is the error you'd get out of `var names = ;`, so make sure the `echo` doesn't output an empty string. There's not enough info in the question to say if that's the only problem

Comment: I will write whole php. Problem is if I remove words with special characters there is no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that there was no meta charset utf8. I added it and now everything works.